# In Intellij idea, how to show target dir when .gitignore file contain 'target/'

Tags: intellij-idea

### intellij verison

- IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 (Ultimate Edition)
- Build #IU-193.5233.102, built on November 28, 2019
- Runtime version: 11.0.4+10-b520.11 x86_64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
- macOS 10.15.2

### `show excluded files` is checked.

### intellij does not show target directory.

When I add 'target/' to .gitignore file. As follows

.gitignore file:

```
.idea
*.iml
target/
```

### intellij show target directory.

When I delete 'target/' in .gitignore file. As follows

.gitignore file:

```
.idea
*.iml
#target/
```